# Time activity creation error-Intuit Partner Platform-Quickbooks online

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Trying to create a time record and it is throwing error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimeActivity xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<TxnDate>2013-02-18-07:00</TxnDate>
<Employee>
    <EmployeeId idDomain="QBO">2</EmployeeId>
</Employee>
<CustomerId>3</CustomerId>
<ItemId>1</ItemId>  
<StartTime>2013-02-18T11:45:00-07:00</StartTime>
<EndTime>2013-02-18T13:15:00-07:00</EndTime>  
<HourlyRate>10.5</HourlyRate>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
<Hours>10</Hours>
<Description>This is a Description</Description>
</TimeActivity>
```

Other information include:
1. valid OAuth signature, which is working for other requests.
2. Content type set to application/xml
3. URL https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/time-activity/v2/actual_real_id
4. Http method set to POST

Error returned is invalid OAuth signature, which is misleading because the same OAuth header is working for all other requests.

Also, I just tried with a different request, as per your documentation but same results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimeActivity xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<TxnDate>2013-02-18-07:00</TxnDate>
<Employee>
    <EmployeeId idDomain="QBO">2</EmployeeId>
</Employee>
<CustomerId>3</CustomerId>
<ItemId>1</ItemId>  
<BillableStatus>NotBillable</BillableStatus>
<Hours>8</Hours>
<Minutes>0</Minutes>
<StartTime>2013-02-18T11:45:00-07:00</StartTime>
<EndTime>2013-02-18T13:15:00-07:00</EndTime>
</TimeActivity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REST Clients for browsers have issues with Oauth and POST, it does not correctly generate the signature to include the content of the body.

Try it with the API Explorer, it should work fine.
http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com

regards,
Jarred

Comment: Thank you Jarred, it really saved lot of time. Excellent tool :)

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are using looks incorrect.

You're using this URL:

> https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/time-activity/v2/

Which is missing the realm ID. It should look something like:

> https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/time-activity/v2/*12341234*

Where that 12341324 is your realm ID. I'm not sure if that's a bug in a DevKit you're using or just your code, but that would be the place to start looking into.

Comment: Yes, it is qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/time-activity/v2/<realmId>; I am testing using Restclient Firefox plugin before writing the code and these error are from RestClient.